# jQuery UI images in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, jquery-ui, assetic

I'm having issues getting the images from jQuery-ui to show up properly in my symfony2 application.

The setup is straightforward - I used composer to get the "components/jqueryui" and included this in my config file:

```
assets:
    css_jqueryui:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css
        filters: [cssrewrite]
```

However the images are broken - I get a 404 error and the paths get rewritten to `../../images/*` (with or **without** the rewrite filter).